# Excel VBA insert page break every nth row

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code which does everything except insert the page break after row 35.  can anyone help please?

```
Sub PrintSet()

    Dim rs As Worksheet
    Dim sPrintArea As String

    sPrintArea = "A1:AE65"
    For Each rs In Sheets
        rs.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
        rs.PageSetup.Zoom = False
        rs.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
        rs.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 2
        rs.PageSetup.PrintArea = sPrintArea
        rs.HPageBreaks.Add before:=Range("A36")                               
     Next rs

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the last line like this:

```
rs.HPageBreaks.Add before:=rs.Range("A36")
```

Thus, you are adding a reference `rs` also. It should work better. See what Microsoft says about referencing ranges:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221547(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: None of these seem to make a change - the page break is firmly staying put!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Dim hpgbr As HPageBreak
Dim hpgbrs As HPageBreaks
Set hpgbr = hpgbrs.Add(Before:=Range("A36"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. I removed the Zoom

```
Sub PrintSet()
Dim rs As Worksheet
Dim sPrintArea As String

    sPrintArea = "A1:AE65"
    For Each rs In Sheets
        rs.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape
        rs.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1
        rs.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 2
        rs.PageSetup.PrintArea = sPrintArea
        rs.HPageBreaks.Add before:=Range("A36")
    Next rs
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately this hasn't worked - the page break is still at row 46